# Testing ria services authentication with moq

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, authentication, moq, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA Services authentication in a Silverlight app and it works great. Now I want to add unit tests using Moq framework: http://code.google.com/p/moq/

The problem I'm having is that I can't simulate none of the methods exposed by WebContext.Current.Authentication, since I can't return custom values for the mocked methods. For example, I can't simulate a successful login since I can't set a value for LoadUserOperation.IsComplete because that property doesn't have a public setter. The same happens with all the returned structures: they are readonly!

Is there a way I can simulate the authentication operations and therefore test the login in my app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help.
I found a solution after refactoring the code a little bit and adding proper interfaces and wrappers for the RIA services sealed classes. [This guy shows how.](http://xamlcoder.com/blog/2010/01/17/unit-testing-asynchronous-ria-service-calls-in-silverlight-using-rhino-mocks-and-nunit/)

Answer (score 1):

I show how to mock authentication in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/07/14/mocking-ria-services-authentication-and-authorization.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @kyle-mcclellan, but I was looking for a way to mock the RIA services sealed classes. After some research I found it was possible if I refactored the code a little bit. I'm posting the answer in this thread.